# How to use :nth-child() for different background-colors when adding elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I just discovered the `:nth-child()` selector and it works great. I wanted to be able to give changing background-colors to divs when I display them on my site.
Like this here

```
<div class="background-color">Content</div> <!-- White background-color -->
<div class="background-color">Content</div> <!-- Black background-color -->
<div class="background-color">Content</div> <!-- White background-color -->
<div class="background-color">Content</div> <!-- Black background-color -->
```

and so on. All of that works just great. The only problem I have is, if I add a new div through a JS function, it won't alternate `background-color`. It will always have a white background-color. Within the JS function, I add the same CSS classes and everything, but it is still not working.

Is there a way for me to display new divs added by the user in the right color?

Comment: Can you include `css`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Show your CSS code...

Comment: "if I add a new div through a JS function, it won't alternate background-color" - since this is the basis of your question, you should include this javascript function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `nth-child(even)` for this sort of application:

```
.background-color {
    background-color: white;
}

.background-color:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86nkhwkz/

Every child (assuming they are all of class `background-color`) will then alternate background colors.

Comment: this would be ineffective for dynamically added divs, won't it be?

Comment: No. CSS rules are applied to all elements the instant they are reflected in the DOM, dynamically added or not. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/86nkhwkz/2/

Comment: That works fine. Thank you. The only important thing to keep in mind is that none of this will work if there are any other elements between the different div tags.I am sure that you already know this but i thought it might be still usefull to have it on here.  I will check your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: The rules would still work, however the style would not be applied to those elements that don't have the class applied. You can remove the class from the divs in the middle of my JSFiddle example, and you'll notice that they will render as divs without any styling. The alternating background-colors will continue once you resume using the class.

Answer (score 1):

Always show your code so we can fix it.

```js
function add() {
  var $d = $("<div>");
  $d.addClass("background-color").html("Content");
  $("#wrapper").append($d);
}
```

```css
#wrapper > div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  color: red
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="background-color">Content</div>
  <div class="background-color">Content</div>
  <div class="background-color">Content</div>
  <div class="background-color">Content</div>
</div>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```